# Get ThreadName from ThreadID

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there a way to get a Thread's ThreadName from a ThreadId? (from say, a ThreadID like 10, or 15, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in managed code. You can't even get a list of [`Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) objects for the current process, as far as I'm aware. You can get the `ProcessThread`s with [`Process.Threads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx) and `ProcessThread` provides an [`Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.id.aspx) property, if that helps you... but a [`ProcessThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx) doesn't have a name as far as I can tell :(

Comment: Oh.. That's quite a pity then cause the System.Diagnostics.TraceListener class has methods that allows you to get a Thread ID via TraceEventCache.ThreadId, except that a number is not very meaningful as it doesn't say alot.. and varies from run to run too! :(

Comment: Are these your own threads? If so, when you create the thread you could log the name and ID, and match them up later.

Answer (score 2):

The best information that I could find is here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/advanced-dotnet@discuss.develop.com/msg07369.html

That doesn't seem too helpful, though.  It seems that there is no good way to do this, short of you changing the code to maintain a list (or dictionary) of all of your application's threads.